# How do I update with a newly-created detached entity using NHibernate?

Tags: web-services, nhibernate, serialization, session-state, entity-relationship

## Explanation:

Let's say I have an object graph that's nested several levels deep and each entity has a bi-directional relationship with each other.

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

Or in other words, `A` has a collection of `B` and `B` has a reference back to `A`, and `B` has a collection of `C` and `C` has a reference back to `B`, etc...

Now let's say I want to edit some data for an instance of`C`. In Winforms, I would use something like this:

```
var instanceOfC;

using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    // get the instance of C with Id = 3
    instanceOfC = session.Linq<C>().Where(x => x.Id == 3);
}

SendToUIAndLetUserUpdateData(instanceOfC);

using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    // re-attach the detached entity and update it
    session.Update(instanceOfC);
}
```

In plain English, we grab a persistent instance out of the database, detach it, give it to the UI layer for editing, then re-attach it and save it back to the database.

## Problem:

This works fine for Winform applications because we're using the same entity all throughout, the only difference being that it goes from persistent to detached to persistent again.

The problem is that now I'm using a web service and a browser, sending over JSON data. The entity gets serialized into a string, and de-serialized into a **new** entity. It's no longer a detached entity, but rather a transient one that just happens to have the same ID as the persistent one (and updated fields). If I use this entity to update, it will wipe out the relationship to `B` and `D` because they don't exist in this new transient entity.

## Question:

My question is, how do I serialize detached entities over the web to a client, receive them back, and save them, while preserving any relationships that I didn't explicitly change? I know about `ISession.SaveOrUpdateCopy` and `ISession.Merge()` (they seem to do the same thing?), but this will still wipe out the relationships if I don't explicitly set them. I could copy the fields from the transient entity to the persistent entity one by one, but this doesn't work too well when it comes to relationships and I'd have to handle version comparisons manually.

Comment: I'd also like to add that I haven't been able to find any resources online that cover this issue. All the NHibernate guides I've found on detached entities talk about it either as a reference that you keep around within one application's scope, or deal with it as a single entity with no relationships to any other entities.

Comment: Hi did you ever get an answer to this question?

Comment: Hi CraftyFella, I just posted an answer detailing what I did in my case.

Comment: merge and saveorupdatecopy do the same thing, but saveorupdatecopy is no longer used, merge is api standard moving forward.

Comment: From my experience, `Merge()` has the same problem with nulling out the relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using an intermediate class to hold data coming in from the web service, then copying its properties to the database entity. For example, let's say I have two entities like so:

### Entity Classes

```
public class Album
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection Photos { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string PathToFile { get; set; }
}
```

`Album` contains a collection of `Photo` objects, and `Photo` has a reference back to the `Album` it's in, so it's a bidirectional relationship. I then create a `PhotoDTO` class:

### DTO Class

```
public class PhotoDTO
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    // note that the DTO does not have a PathToFile property
}
```

Now let's say I have the following `Photo` stored in the database:

### Server Data

```
new Photo
{
    Id = 15,
    Name = "Fluffy Kittens",
    Album = Session.Load<Album>(3)
};
```

The client now wants to update the photo's name. They send over the following JSON to the server:

### Client Data

PUT http://server/photos/15

```
{
    "id": 15,
    "albumid": 3,
    "name": "Angry Kittens"
}
```

The server then deserializes the JSON into a `PhotoDTO` object. On the server side, we update the `Photo` like this:

### Server Code

```
var photoDTO = DeserializeJson();
var photoDB = Session.Load(photoDTO.Id); // or use the ID in the URL

// copy the properties from photoDTO to photoDB
photoDB.Name = photoDTO.Name;
photoDB.Album = Session.Load<Album>(photoDTO.AlbumId);

Session.Flush(); // save the changes to the DB
```

### Explanation

This was the best solution I've found because:

1. You can choose which properties the client is allowed to modify. For example, `PhotoDTO` doesn't have a `PathToFile` property, so the client can never modify it.
2. You can also choose whether to update a property or not. For example, if the client didn't send over an `AlbumId`, it will be 0. You can check for that and not change the `Album` if the ID is 0. Likewise, if the user doesn't send over a `Name`, you can choose not to update that property.
3. You don't have to worry about the lifecycle of an entity because it will always be retrieved and updated within the scope of a single session.

### AutoMapper

I recommend using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to automatically copy the properties from the DTO to the entity, especially if your entites have a lot of properties. It saves you the trouble of having to write every property by hand, and has a lot of configurability.